# p5.js: why is my copied image flattened and duplicated?

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to manipulate pixel data for a school assignment. In one of the sections, I am trying to obtain the pixel data of an image and copy it into a buffer. However, the buffer looks like this beside the original image, where the buffer is flattened significantly and contains 2 of the same image. Why is this happening?

Original image on left, buffer on the right (grey rect is just the background):
[image]

The buffer is 512x512, exactly the same as the original image, when I checked it in console, yet it looks like that.

Code I used for the copying:

```
imgs[0].loadPixels();
avgImg.loadPixels();
    
    for(var y = 0; y < imgs[0].height; ++y) {
        for(var x = 0; x < imgs[0].width; ++x) {
            var index = (y * imgs[0].width + x) * 4;
            avgImg.pixels[index] = imgs[0].pixels[index];
            avgImg.pixels[index + 1] = imgs[0].pixels[index + 1]
            avgImg.pixels[index + 2] = imgs[0].pixels[index + 2]
            avgImg.pixels[index + 3] = imgs[0].pixels[index + 3]
        }
    }

    avgImg.updatePixels();
    image(avgImg, avgImg.width, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you taking [`pixelDensity `](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixelDensity) into account when using [`pixels[]`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels) ? (Maybe you're on a retina or other hi-res display (perhaps twice the density, hence the double image) ?). 
(Other than that, if you use `x,y` only to get the pixel index, you can simply use one flat for loop to go through each entry (incremeting accordingly).)

Comment: I have a `pixelDensity(1);` in my `setup()`, I'm not sure if that is enough

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that includes the `setup()` and `draw()` functions

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem, although I do not really understand why.

This was the `setup()` originally:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(imgs[0].width * 2, imgs[0].height);
    avgImg = createGraphics(imgs[0].width, imgs[0].height);
    
    pixelDensity(1);
}
```

After swapping the positions of `pixelDensity()` and the declaration for avgImg, it worked.

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(imgs[0].width * 2, imgs[0].height);
    pixelDensity(1);
    
    avgImg = createGraphics(imgs[0].width, imgs[0].height);
}
```